Detrmine the length of the diagonal of a parallelepiped knowing that $a(a^2+3)=b^2+c^2-2a^2+4$
the problem
Detrmine the length of the diagonal of a parallelepiped with the dimensions $a,b,c \in(0, \infty)$ which satisfy all of the following equalities:
$a(a^2+3)=b^2+c^2-2a^2+4$
$b(b^2+3)=a^2+c^2-2b^2+4$
$c(c^2+3)=b^2+a^2-2c^2+4$
the idea
So we need to process all of this equalities to find the value of $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$
All I could thought of is to factorize  $(a+2)(a^2+3)=b^2+c^2+10$ and the analogous, but I don't know if this helps. I also thought of using modular arithmetic.
Hope one fo you can help me! Thanks !

Are you sure about the target expression? That's the diagonal of a cuboid. You seem to be missing a few terms.

How do you know that the parallelepiped is a rectangular parallelepiped?

@user2661923 Sorry, the problem specified its an rectangular one.

@user170231 Sorry, the problem specified its an rectangular one.

In the first equation, "complete the cube":
$$\begin{align*}
a (a^2+3) &= b^2 + c^2 - 2a^2 + 4 \\
a^3 \color{red}{+3a^2} + 3a \color{red}{+1} &= a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 5 \\
(a+1)^3 - 5 &= a^2+b^2+c^2
\end{align*}$$
By a similar token,
$$\begin{align*}
(b+1)^3 - 5 &= a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \\
(c+1)^3 - 5 &= a^2 + b^2 + c^2
\end{align*}$$
Hence $a=b=c$, and the first equation may be solved for $a$:
$$(a+1)^3 - 5 = 3a^2 \implies a^3  + 3a - 4 = 0$$

By inspection is probably the quickest "method", it's easy to spot that $a=1$. Alternatively, since the leading and last coefficients are simple, you can use the rational root theorem to deduce that $a=1$ is a root, and divide the cubic by $a-1$ to recover a quadratic with no other real roots. As a last last resort, you could also employ methods for solving the cubic

Thanks for your answer! I got that a=1, which makes the diagonal $\sqrt{3}$. Is my solution right?

Indeed it is: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+a%5E3+%2B+3a+-+4+%3D+0+over+reals
